# Reloading a CollectionViewController after deleting an object?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `collectionView` that pulls data from a network, then the user deletes an object and I want to display the remaining objects.  Because of past nightmares with removing objects at index and juggling my local data being in sync with the network version, I’m ok with just making a new call to get the new network data (less the deleted object) as it’s not that much.   That being said, what’s the best approach as far as displaying the new data in a still existing `collectionView`?  I kind of want to throw out the `collectionView` (with the old data) and add a new one but there's no such method available to do something like that is there?  Or just refresh the entire `collectionViewController`? Trying to figure out the preferred approach here instead of a hack =)

```
func getPinsCheckLinksAndStartLoadAnimation() {

        PinterestRequest().getPinterstPins(board: board) { (result) in

            LinkCheck().checkLinks(pins: result, handler: { (testPinsWithBrokenLinks, error) in

                self.pinsWithBrokenLinks = testPinsWithBrokenLinks
            })

            self.startAnimating(self.view.frame.size, message: "Checking Pins...", messageFont: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16), type: .ballScaleMultiple, color: UIColor.red, padding: CGFloat(0), displayTimeThreshold: nil, minimumDisplayTime: nil, backgroundColor: UIColor.clear, textColor: UIColor.black)  //see https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView#defaults
        }

    }
```

Comment: I just reload the collectionView with the updated data.

Comment: The only problem with that is I use a loading animation, which will then display over the old collectionView cells until it reloads.

Comment: You mean like a `UIRefreshControl`? Post some of your code so that I can get a better idea.

Comment: It's a custom library, added the function I call when the objects are deleted above

Comment: `pinsWithBrokenLinks` is computed property that reloads the `collectionView` when it changes

Comment: So if you just called `collectionView.reloadData()` your animation would display? I would separate out that functionality.

Comment: You know the more I think about it you're right, I was thinking it would be bad UI to go from the old `collectionView` to the new one (-1) but it really isn't, I think I'm just going to handle this way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you don't want to keep a local version in sync and delete the cell at index, then your best bet is to do collectionView.reloadData().

The BEST way and the way I do it, is with Realm. Which is a local database that I keep synced with Firebase or my own server. It takes care of deleting cells at index by just deleting the object locally and then you can delete the object on your server with an api call.

But other than that you'll just have to reload the whole collectionView.